# Facebook Login Error Using Parse Javascript SDK

Tags: android, facebook, parsing, cordova, authentication

I'm trying to log into Facebook via Parse in a PhoneGap project made for Android.

When I try to run the HTML locally, the pop-up will appear but I get the generic "an error occurred" message. When I run the Android project, the Facebook pop-up/redirect won't even appear.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.0.8.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        Parse.initialize("XXXXXXX", 
        "YYYYYY");

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        Parse.FacebookUtils.init({
        appId      : 'ZZZZZZZ', // App ID
        channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
    Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(null, {
        success: function(user) {
            if (!user.existed()) {
            alert("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
        } else {
            alert("User logged in through Facebook!");
        }
    },
        error: function(user, error) {
            alert("User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize.");
        }
    });
};

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>

    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

So, I'd love to get this working. Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Update - This is the error information I get:

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

Comment: Try setting the `show_error` parameter in the actual method that calls the FB login, that should give you some more information about what went wrong.

Comment: This is the error I got when trying to initialize the FB app, but I don't know where I screwed up.

Error: uncaught exception: 
[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIObserverService.addObserver]"  
nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://browser/content/browser.js :: prepareForStartup :: line 6804"  data: no]

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever find a complete solution for this? I can get around your specific problem by selecting Website with Facebook Login as how my app integrates with Facebook, and setting the website to [http://localhost]. which then works fine within Chrome running off a local server, but then doesn't work on an actual device with the error "The Javascript Facebook SDK must be loaded before calling init" in the Parse JS SDK.